# How to validate that the header application/x-zip-compressed is a ZIP archive?

Tags: c#, mime-types

I am trying to implement a IsValidMime method to check that the magic header of a .zip file is actually a zip file.

I've looked everywhere for the header magic value for  ***application/x-zip-compressed***, but can't seem to find it anywhere..

For **application/zip** mime I know is the '50 4B 03 04' and it works.

Edit:
I zip on windows and I am using .ZIP.

To get the mimeMapping I am using:

```
MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName) from System.Web;
```

To compare that the file has the magic header:

```
 file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(zipHeader);
```

Comment: Are you using ZIP or GZIP?

Comment: I've updated the description.

Comment: A ZIP is a ZIP. If it opens as a ZIP, it'll have the same magic regardless of the MIME type, and then `application/x-zip-compressed` is just the same as `application/zip` but using an unregistered `x-` type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert seems logic to me, but it doesn't behave as you are describing when I try to read the bytes from the file with file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(zipHeader); What I am doing wrong  ?

Comment: Potentially nothing. Maybe some funky mapping is going on to a file that is not actually, truly a ZIP file, but opens correctly with an archive manager because it is some form of supported archive. Under Linux I'd be using `file` to see if the magic matches anything known. Note that ZIP itself has a little more than these 4 magic bytes; apparently `PK\x05\x06` is used for an empty archive and `PK\x07\x08` for a spanned one, if Wikipedia is to be believed. Check if the file perhaps only starts with `PK` (`0x50 0x4b`). Note that magic alone does little to verify the file is truly valid.

Comment: Not all zip are the same and not all tools work with all versions. See Wiki and report the other header bits :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)